# Como mostrar aviso "Atualize seu Navegador" quando este não der suporte ao HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Como mostrar o aviso **"Atualize seu Navegador"** quando o navegador do usuário não der suporte as tags do HTML5 ou propriedades do CSS3?

Uma iniciativa que incentiva isso é a do site http://www.updateyourbrowser.net/pt, porém eles disponibilizam um script para isso.

Seria possível fazer isso sem um script em javascript ou jquery, usando apenas técnicas em HTML5 e CSS3?

Por exemplo, se vc usar a tag `<video>` ou `<audio>` colocando um texto dentro dele, antes ou depois das tags `<source>`, como no exemplo abaixo, esse texto só será mostrado quando o navegador não der suporte a essas tags, consequentemente ao html5. Porém não encontrei uma forma boa de estilizar esse aviso. Também não sei se esse aviso seria a melhor forma de fazer isso.

```
<video id="aviso">
   Desculpe mas seu navegador não dá suporte a HTML5
</video>
```

Mesmo que não seja possível, qual a melhor forma de se fazer isso com **javascript/jquery**?

Comment: Você quer avisar ao usuário que o navegador dele não suporta HTML5 utilizando HTML5?

Comment: Sim @Daniel, como acabo de exemplificar na edição que fiz da pergunta. Poderia atualizar a página por favor para melhor análise? Obrigado!

Comment: Uma alternativa que utilizam é através do Modernizr...
http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3630/detectando-suporte-para-html-5.aspx

Comment: Nenhum browser suporta "HTML5"; vários suportam, isso sim, funcionalidades incluídas no HTML5, como as tags VIDEO, CANVAS, etc. Sugiro usar o Modernizr para detectar funcionalidades específicas e mostrar, p.ex., um popup (window.alert) para avisar em caso negativo.

Comment: Obrigado @MarceloBonifazio pela ajuda. Vou apenas aguardar pra ver se alguém conhece uma técnica diferente, livre de scripts. Caso contrário, até o momento, essa é a campeã! Uma outra interessante, caso se interesse em ver, é essa: https://github.com/burocratik/outdated-browser

Comment: @Marcelo Bonifazio  Coloque seu comentário como resposta.

Comment: @RicardoPeres Converti sua resposta para comentário, porque não dava maiores explicações de como fazer. Mesmo assim, você tem razão em dizer que "HTML5" não existe. Cada browser suporta um conjunto diferente de recursos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem apenas duas maneiras que eu conheço de descobrir se um navegador suporta ou não os padrões `HTML5` e `CSS3`

A primeira é verificando o `User Agent` do navegador, e fazendo o tratamento de acordo com o resultado, você pode descobrir isso via **servidor** que recebeu a requisição de resposta, e na resposta já fazer o tratamento da página a ser renderizada, ou via **cliente**, e renderizar no próprio cliente.

**PHP**

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

**JS**

```
function UserAgente(){
      var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
      return ua;
}
```

Com isso fazer uma verificação de compatibilidade de acordo com a versão do navegador utilizado pelo cliente....

[Aqui você encontra uma lista completa de User Agents](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php)

Essa forma de fato é a mais árdua e trabalhosa.....

A segunda forma é utilizar `Modernizr` para detectar se o navegador aceita tal recurso, essa é a forma mais indicada.

Para tanto não há nenhum outro segredo, basta importar a biblioteca e testar as funcionalidades de acordo com a sua necessidade.

[A documentação completa você encontra aqui.](http://modernizr.com/)

**Obs:** Mais um detalhe, isso vai de opinião própria (no caso a minha) não adianta tentarmos fazer com que o cliente atualize o navegador.... isso so gera desconforto para aqueles que já não vem a tecnologia com bons olhos, o que vale mais a pena é tentar produzir algo que funcione em todos os ambientes possíveis... mesmo que fique com cara feia, o que importa é o resultado esperado ser obtido.

Comment: Obrigado! Concordo contigo quanto a acessibilidade. Porém, o uso que irei dar para este script é em um sistema para lojistas, e não na loja em si. Ou seja, é algo bem específico. Para as lojas, a acessibilidade é o que manda! ;)

Answer (score 5):

Você não pode detectar “suporte ao HTML5", mas é possível verificar o suporte a funcionalidades individuais, como canvas, vídeo, ou geolocalização.

Existem 4 técnicas para  detectar se os browsers detectam alguma funcionalidade. 
São elas:

1  - Verifica se uma determinada propriedade existe em um objeto global (como window ou navigator).

**Exemplo**: [testando o suporte a geolocalização](http://diveintohtml5.com.br/detect.html#geolocation)

2 - Crie um elemento, então verifique se uma determinada propriedade existe naquele elemento.

**Exemplo**: [testanto suporte ao canvas](http://diveintohtml5.com.br/detect.html#canvas)

3 - Crie um elemento, verifique se um determinado método existe naquele elemento, então chame o método e verifique o valor que ele retorna.

**Exemplo**: [testando quais formatos de vídeos são suportados](http://diveintohtml5.com.br/detect.html#video-formats)

4 - Crie um elemento, defina uma propriedade para um determinado valor, então verifique se a propriedade manteve seu valor.

**Exemplo**: [testando quais tipos de `<input>` são suportados](http://diveintohtml5.com.br/detect.html#input-types)

**Fonte**: [Detectando Funcionalidades do HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.com.br/detect.html)

Answer (score 4):

Olá, como nosso amigo @Ricardo Peres disse, basta usar o  http://modernizr.com/

Coloque-o na sua pagina.

```
<script src="modernizr.min.js"></script>
```

E faça

```
if (Modernizr.canvas) {
  // Suporta HTML5
} else {
  // não suporta
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas a mesma já foi dada via comentário pelo @MarceloBonifazio. A pergunta proposta é mais para se existe uma técnica livre de scripts. Ainda assim, muito obrigado pelas sugestões!

Comment: Pede p/ ele colocar como resposta

Answer (score -2):

Poderia usar browse happy para avisar o usuario para atualizar o navegador

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a
href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->
```

http://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/nmbzg

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão. Mas, se é para usar scripts, há opções melhores, como o Modernizr, já mencionado, e o https://github.com/burocratik/outdated-browser. ;)